# Please join me in thanking George (a.k.a. grgarside) on his earning 100k reputation

Tags: discussion

We have a new [100k reputation contributer to the site](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/46/alltime/apple/).

[George a.k.a grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside) has passed the 100k mark and has clearly done an amazing job at documenting useful, clear, helpful answers.

[image]

He stands alone atop the most [highly voted answer category](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer) and my hat is off to him

Thank you for your many hours of contributions to documenting how things work, how to fix them when broken and how to take action to contribute to this body of knowledge that is available around the world. Thanks also to everyone who votes here and edits here since the people that get votes only get that when others appreciate and *(hopefully politely or kindly)* criticize posts that could be improved or clarified.

Comment: Here here! Well done George! :) And thank you for all your efforts!

Comment: Monumental. Well done!

Comment: Nice one, George :) Well done.

Comment: Thank you all! It's a pleasure to do a bit of problem solving here in my spare time, and I look forward to the next 100k person!

Comment: Thank you George! kudos :)

Comment: you do yeoman's work grgarside

Comment: Nice ASCII art, must take lots of patience and creativity

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Hip! Hip! Hooray!

Comment: <Raises a pint in a toast>  Congrats!

Comment:  Nice job! Congrats!

Comment: Nice milestone to cross with lots of great answers and help provided along the way! Congratulations!